# Tensorflow DNNClassifier loss goes low but terrible accuracy precision recall

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I am using 0.10rc0 Tensorflow's contrib.learn.DNNClassifier to learn a binary classification problem.  The loss drops from initially being in the thousands to around 0.7, but accuracy and precision hover around 50% while recall has dropped to 0.0001.  Using another optimizer loss dropped to around 70, accuracy/precision hovered around 50% and recall was around 20%.

Question: how is it possible for loss to drop while accuracy/precision/recall remain terrible?

I can understand if the loss function was bad, but I'm using TF's DNNClassifier and so they've specified the loss function.  I imagine they know what they are doing in that department.  Here are some additional facts that may be relevant:

- training data size is 1.3 million, validation data size is 0.3 million, and there are 150 features per record
- batch size is 50,000
- the mean of the target column for the validation set is 0.517 so the data is very evenly split between positive (1) and negative (0) samples of the class
- the loss for both training and validation data is around 0.7 so I think it's not an overfitting problem since they are the same (correct me if that assumption is invalid)

Here's the latest validation step output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Validation (step 9280): labels/actual_target_mean = 0.517459, labels/prediction_mean = 0.498576, recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.000114476, recall = 0.000114476, auc = 0.499985, precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.487179, precision = 0.487179, loss = 0.721832, accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean = 0.482538, global_step = 9280, accuracy/baseline_target_mean = 0.517459, accuracy = 0.482538
```

What am I missing???

Comment: 0.7 loss is not low, did you try training for more epochs and see if the loss decreases?

Comment: Maybe that misunderstanding is my problem.  I figured since it had dropped from many thousands to 0.7 that it was pretty far along.  But so if the 0.7 loss is not that good, I think my question still stands about why is it possible for loss to drop so dramatically, but accuracy/precision/recall are still terrible?  Another optimize had 70 loss and similar accuracy/precision and much better recall.  That's really the biggest confusion for me.

Comment: Interpreting particular loss values depends on which loss function is being used, which one are you using? You also didn't answer my question about further training.

Comment: I'm using TF's DNNClassifier, so as I understand it- it's using whatever loss function they set for it.  I've checked the init and fit method parameters and don't see anywhere to set a loss function.  As for further training, sorry for not answering that- those values are where it seemed to plateau.  The plateau was at least 500-1000 epochs long in both cases.